# Resize transparent images in windows mobile using C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Is there a way to re-size a transparent image in windows mobile(C#)? I can re-size the image but I am losing the transparency. It is being replaced with white.

Here is what I have now

```
public static void ResizePicture(string imageFileName, Size maxSize)
{
    using (Image src = new Bitmap(imageFileName))
    {
        using (Bitmap dst = new Bitmap(maxSize.Width, maxSize.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(dst))
            {

                ImageAttributes imageAttr = new ImageAttributes();
                g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, dst.Width, dst.Height), 0, 0, src.Width, src.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttr);
            }
            dst.Save(imageFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this as found in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172507.aspx) about setting the transparency color. It looks like you need to set the `SetColorKey` for this to work. See also [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/5624c89d-0e57-4d3f-90c4-eabc676e05f1/) that explains you cannot set the transparency (apparently contradicting the first link). But, you can still down the Smart Devices Framework (community edition) found in [OpenNetCF.org](http://www.opennetcf.org) and use that instead to handle the transparency workaround. I would try the first link before going any further to see if that works.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

The CF has, in my opinion anyway, a bug.  Graphics.Clear with Color.Transparent [actually fills the image with white, not transparent](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/10/28/ProjectResistanceDay4GraphicFixesAndMoreGesturing.aspx).  The workaround is tedious.  See the link above.